# Removing TLSv1.0 in WSO2 EMM 1.1.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I am setting up a new WSO2 EMM server and, in order to maintain my organization's PCI DSS certification, I have to disable support for any encryption protocol lower than TLSv1.1 before I can put it into production (see [this](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/Migrating_from_SSL_Early_TLS_Information%20Supplement_v1.pdf) for more information on PCI 3.1).

I edited the file /repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml as per [the documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/Configuring+Transport+Level+Security). Here is what I tried:

- I changed the attribute `sslEnabledProtocols` from `TLS` to `TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2`, but this generates the error

> ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat} - 
>   LifeCycleException while starting tomcat connector
>   {org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat}

in my `wso2carbon.log` and I'm unable to log into the EMM web console.

Does anyone know how to disable TLSv1.0 without breaking my installation?

cheers,

Answer (score 1):

Found it!
you have to get rid of sslProtocol attribute and replace it with sslEnabledProtocols, they look very similar.